# Conditional Alias in SQL

Tags: sql-server, alias

Is there any way to give conditional alias to SQL columns?.

Because I have two tables for `Fields` and `Category`. Meaning of each field changes conditionally.

```
 DECLARE @f1 NVARCHAR(10);
 set @f1= (select Field1 from Category);
 select Field1 as @f1 from AdditionalFields
```

Comment: In Oracle we have dynamic SQL. SQL Server must be having an equivalent feature.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [dynamic query](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).

> ```
>  DECLARE @f1 NVARCHAR(10);
>  set @f1= 'MyCategory'
>
>  DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(MAX);
>  SET @CMD = 'SELECT Field1 AS ' + @f1 + ' FROM MyTable';
>
>  SELECT @CMD;
>   --EXEC (@CMD);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                         |
> | :--------------------------------------- |
> | SELECT Field1 AS MyCategory FROM MyTable |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4604cda311ff42bc0404ac0f92eac8b0)*